# how to implement spring AOP in .NET

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to create a sipmle application using spring AOP in C#.please help to me for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? What type of application do you want to create? If you are looking for samples, you can find them in the 'example'where you extracted Spring.Net (i.e. `examples\Spring\Spring.AopQuickStart`)

You can also find some guidelines [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html).